# Jagged shadow line on sphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Blender newbie here.

I've created a really simple scene consisting of a subdivided and smoothed sphere, then applied a texture and created a Sun light. Rendering in Cycles I'm experiencing a very odd looking shadow edge. Anyone encountered anything like this? From Maya I'm used to be able to increase the sample of individual lights but I can't seem to see a similar option.

[image: Jagged shadow edge with single sun source]

I'm in 2.8 by the way.

By comparison the shadow is actually looking pretty decent in Eevee without changing anything.

Thanks for all your expertise!

Comment: try to increase your lamp size

Comment: May I ask how exactly I can do that with a sun light? Can't seem to find any options for it. I've solved the jagged line but the shadow is still very hard and I'd like to soften the falloff a bit. Thanks! :)

Comment: Never mind, turned out to just be called 'angle' instead. Thanks all!

Comment: yes I think it's called Angle in 2.8   ;)